# Filtering a page with infinite scroll in AngularJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, angularjs, express

I implemented an infinite scrolling feature on my AngularJS + Node.js app.

It is based on this JSfiddle and works the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/
HTML:

```
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];

  var counter = 0;
   $scope.loadMore = function() {
     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({id: counter});
        counter += 10;
     }
   };

  $scope.loadMore();
}

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
  return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];

    elm.bind('scroll', function() {
        if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
            scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
        }
    });
  };
});
```

​

My reasons for implementing the infinite scroll is in order to save my users bandwidth by not loading all 1000 results and their corresponding images unless the user wants to see all of it.

However when searching within the results using an AngularJS filter I am encountering problems, because of course not all the results are there (unless the user has scrolled to the very bottom) so the search will only return a fraction of the required results.

I then removed the infinite scrolling feature in order to have the search function work properly but this provided new issues on chrome (not on Firefox though) when I open the page the browser starts loading images from the top. If I then filter the results by searching for something starting with "z" (at the very bottom of the results) Firefox switches focus and loads the results starting with "z" first (as they are then the only ones being displayed). However chrome continues loading through the list and thus the user will only see the results of their search (for "z") once all the images in the app have been loaded.

I am looking for a way to have angular provide both the infinite scroll and a proper search filter on the results at the same time. If this is not possible then a way to make chrome load the visible images first.

I am currently trying some weird stuff with a bunch of different arrays in the scope but I haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Another example of the use case is in the AngularJS tutorial. If  [this page](http://angular.github.com/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones): had 1 million results, the images were high resolution, and the user searched for the ZZZOOM Phone 5000 then how would I make sure chrome loads the image of the ZZZOOM PHone 5000 before loading all the images of the other phones. 

(The way IE, Firefox and Safari already do automatically.)

Answer (score 8):

Since several people here had a similar issue and I was struggling myself, I took the time to create a fiddle that works (for my case).

https://jsfiddle.net/lisapfisterer/Lu4sbxps/

The main idea is to **dynamically extend the limitTo value** using infinite-scroll's function call

```
<div infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="20">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="logEvent in logEventFilter = (logEvents | filter:searchTerm | limitTo:numberToDisplay) track by $index">
        <td> {{$index}} </td>
        <td> {{logEvent.name}} </td>
        <td> {{numberToDisplay}} </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

loadMore just increases the limit

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    if ($scope.numberToDisplay + 5 < $scope.logEvents.length) {
        $scope.numberToDisplay += 5;
    } else {
        $scope.numberToDisplay = $scope.logEvents.length;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is really working for me, but partially, since I load the "logEvents" only when "deviceReady" is fired, I can't do it before. My problem is that $scope.logEvents is undefined when the code is executed. I have tried putting the "loadMore" scope function inside "deviceReady" but is not working. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Now I have been testing this for a while know that loadMore() shouldn't fire at that time, it has to be fired only when scrolling, thats my problem, maybe I'm labeling with infinite-scroll="loadMore()"  the wrong html tag.

Comment: Check if you're using the newest version of infinite-scroll.js v1.2.2 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngInfiniteScroll/1.2.2/ng-infinite-scroll.js). The website only links v1.0.0 but the new version fixed some issues. Also add "if ($scope.logEvents) { ... } to your function so it is only executed if the list is filled.

Comment: Actually I found that the one in cdnjs is outdated too, I took the one from github (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/master/build/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js) and will test it.
Regarding the need of declaring loadMore() when device is ready, I fixed it addin ng-if="!isLoading" to the tag that has infinite-scroll="loadMore()", that makes the html load after I got the data... but I really keep thinking the loadMore() is firing before the DOM of the list is rendered, since its firing at the beginning, and only ONCE :/

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do isn't "impossible" but it's certainly going to be a little complicated.

- Have your server do all of the "filtering" to ensure that the paginated values returned are the proper values for the filter(s).
- When the server returns the results, render all of the HTML to the screen *except the src attributes of image tags*. This way none of the images will begin loading yet.
- Scroll to the proper "page".
- Make sure all of the heights prior to the images being loaded are the same, now do some JS magic to figure out which ones are visible.
- Set the src attribute of the visible images only, Subscribe to their "load" events and create a $q promise that is complete once all loads are complete.
- after that promise completes, set the rest of the image src attributes so the remainder of the images will load.

Comment: Thanks for your post. In the end the solution was extremely simple all I had to do was change the way the infinite scroll worked. 


Instead of pushing to the shortend array in the scope I did that inside a filter. The filter takes the complete array as its argument and looks like this - searchFilter:text:count


The filter limits the length of the returned array based on count and count increases each time you scroll to the bottom of the page.


I will post a working JSFiddle a bit later today so other people can see it.

Comment: Bump... Where is that fiddle @RickKleinhans? eheh :)